# How to enter newline in table cell where the text orientation is vertical (Libreoffice Writer)?

Tags: libreoffice, text-processing

In Libreoffice Writer (Version: 4.3.7.2), how do I enter a newline in a table cell where the text orientation is vertical?

My operating system is Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS Trusty.

I have a table cell that contains a single line of text whose orientation is vertical.  In the same cell, I want to enter another line of vertically oriented text to the right of the current line, but pressing `Enter` and/or `Shift+Enter` creates a new line underneath the vertical text, not to the right, which is what I want.

Basically, what I want is for when I rotate the page 90 degrees to read the vertical text, the multiple lines of text in the cell read downward, just like if I were to read multiple lines of text that are horizontally oriented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try pressing Shift-Enter after "Line 1" and type "Line 2"

[image: Table cell with two vertical lines of text]

Comment: I tried pressing Shift-Enter after "Line 1", "Line 2" appears before (below) "Line 1", so it looks like it's on the same line, not to the right as it appears in your example.  I also tried Shift-Enter with the cursor at the start of "Line 1", same result.

Comment: What version of LibreOffice Writer are you using? The screenshot is from the latest release (Version 4.2.8.2) of LibreOffice for Linux Mint.  It sounds like Enter and Shift-Enter have the same effect for you.  On my system Enter works as you describe (Line 2Line 1 displayed vertically), but Shift-Enter gives the result shown.

Comment: I'm using LibreOfficer Writer (Version: 4.3.7.2) on Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS Trusty.  Both Enter and Shift-Enter have the same effect for me.

Comment: I tried Trusty (which included LO 4.3.7.2) on my machine using a Live USB and could get Line 1 and Line 2 oriented vertically using Shift-Enter as shown in my screenshot.  I don't know what else to suggest to truly solve your issue.  However, if you need to work around the problem and just carry on, create an image of the vertical text and insert that into the cell as the title.  You won't be able to edit it directly, but it will look the part!

Comment: It works!  Once I widened the cell, Shift+Enter worked as you had stated and as desired.  For whatever reason, if the cell is not wide enough, then it will not work.